# Align a link/button to the right and bottom of a container that have also other elements - can't use flex

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

Align a link/button to the right and bottom of a container that have also other elements. I can't use flex.

I found some solutions here the majority of them using position relative on parent, and absolute on children, but I couldn't align as I wanted;

I can't modify the class `.right` and `.button`, I need to be set this way, because this is just a component/section.

**Want:**

- the links view1, view2 align to the right of div.right and have the same bottom as .thumb (the 3 images)
- if the images are missing, the view links to go to the left;This can be done with another class, that I can add dynamically.

```css
.right {
  display: table-cell;
}

.button {
  display:inline-block;
}

thumbs::after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.thumb { 
  float:left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/50" />
    <p class="text"> Capital remain stand tree answer next fast. Religious our life tax common interesting other. Lay organization model position game.</p>
        <div class="thumbs">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://loremflickr.com/50/50" />
            </div>
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://loremflickr.com/50/50" />
            </div>
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://loremflickr.com/50/50" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="button">View1</a>
        <a href="" class="button">View2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```css
    .right {
display: table-cell;
}
.row {
    position: relative;
 }
.button {
display:inline-block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}

.thumbs {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
thumbs::after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}

.thumb { 
float:left;
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/50" />
            <p class="text"> Capital remain stand tree answer next fast. Religious our life tax common
                interesting other. Lay organization model position game.</p>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="thumbs">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/50/50" />
                </div>
                <div class="thumb">
                    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/50/50" />
                </div>
                <div class="thumb">
                    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/50/50" />
                </div>
            </div>
                <a href="" class="button">View Products</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: if you look at result, the View link is not at the same level as the image, is bellow

Comment: You want it to be bottom aligned with the 3 images ?

Comment: yes, the bottom of the view link the same as the bottom of the 3 images

Comment: Updated code. Please check if you can do something like this ?

Comment: yes, but you added a width to thumbs, I wanted to control the width from backend thru images, not enforced in css

Comment: It would have been avoided if you could use flex. But in your question you mentioned you can't use it. !

Comment: Please check now. I have removed height. Your issue was that you were using float in images, due to which the parent was not taking height. You need to add the styles on thumbs class that I mentioned in updated answer

Comment: I think you have a typo. You missed the dot(.) in front of thumbs class in css